# How to save STL map to file

Tags: file, stl, dictionary

Is it possible to save STL map to file? and I can load the file to map to save time. thanks!

Comment: What is a STL map?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you can do it manually. If not, the easiest way would be to use [`boost.serialization`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html), that comes with support for all standard containers:

```
std::ofstream ofs("output_file");

// create class instance
std::map<int,string> whatever;

// populate map.

// save data to archive
{
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
    // write map instance to archive
    oa << whatever;
    // archive and stream closed when destructors are called
}
```

You can see how the reverse works (reading from archive), and also that you can use also binary archives. (You'll need a bunch of includes too, but you can get these from the documentation.)

Comment: I also found another way , "http://www.codeproject.com/KB/stl/STL_Serialization_Library.aspx", I don't know whether they are the same method.

Comment: Is a pity that there is no way to directly save it/load it from a memory mapped file.

Answer (score 2):

```
template<class A, class B>
void fn SaveMap(std::map<A, B>& savethismap)
{
  ofstream tfStream("filename");
  tfStream << savethismap.size() << std::endl;
  typedef std::pair<const A, B>& pr;
  BOOST_FOREACH(pr p, savethismap)
  {
     tfStream >> p.first << std::endl << p.second << std::endl;
  }
  tfStream.close();
}
```

This saves everything. I templated this just so you can specialize, I tried it using A : std::string and B : int . It worked fine for me.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Question: Yeah, we can call this a "serialization", but it's just writing keys and values into a file. How does this perform(read/write speed, etc.) compare to other serialization methods such as `boost.serialization`? Also, some thoughts: 1) typically we can use just range-based for loop instead of BOOST_FOREACH. 2) typo: direction of `>>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with serialization. Here you can find a tutorial explaining how to do it:
http://www.functionx.com/cpp/articles/serialization.htm

However, I'm not sure if it will save you time.

Comment: Er, what I want is saving the whole Map, while means I don't need to generate the map again, I can read it directly from file.